# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'...Trying to upload a dataframe to a table in Databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have created a dataframe in databricks as a combination of multiple dataframes. I am now trying to upload that df to a table in my database and I have used this code many times before with no problem, but now it is not working.
My code is

```
df.write.saveAsTable("dashboardco.AccountList")
```

getting the error:
AttributeError: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably your `DataFrame` is the Pandas `DataFrame` object, not Spark `DataFrame` object.

try:

```py
spark.createDataFrame(df).write.saveAsTable("dashboardco.AccountList")
```